# Where should I store variables between calls to web.py?

Tags: python, web.py

I am trying to cache some API responses in my website (written with web.py).

Thus I want to save a variable somewhere on the server side between different calls to my webserver.

Were is the best place to store this variables?

I have acctually not been able to find -any- place where I can store them as of yet.

Since my `index` object seems to be re-initialized with every call to the webapp I can not store the varable as an attribute.

Neither do I seem able to reach the variable if I declare them in the script that initialize the webapp.

```
cacheInfo = "something"

class Index: 
  def GET(self):
    render.index(cacheInfo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

Comment: How about in a database?

Comment: I would like to avoid adding a database since I am tring to keep it lightweight. But otherwise it would be my first choice. 
I also would like to avoid writning to file.

Comment: Well it has to be stored *somewhere*...

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a way to store it in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the pickle module. It stores and retrieves variables from files. CGI scripts don't persist between runs, so you need to store the data in a file or database.

Comment: Okey, to bad that there is no easy way to store it in memory between CGI calls.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store global state then you may use database storage (web.db) and save query  in web.ctx on every request using [application processor](http://webpy.org/cookbook/application_processors). You may serialize your data using pickle or json when saving to db.

If you need to store on per user basis then save data in session (web.session).

Answer (score 0):

I use django for web development and I don't about how web.py works but I think you can store it in session context or as a cookie if that variable is per-site-visitor based.